# C# DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI won't run on UnitTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, mstest

I'm using DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI for mvvm in a C# app, and I'm trying to run msTests with it.  Any call that I make from a UnitTest that calls `DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(delegate { //do stuff });` 
works fine when it's called from a single UnitTest (after calling DispatcherHelper.Initialize(), of course).

However, the problem arises when the Unit Test is run in a greater context -- if I run all of the tests for that class (none of which require the use of DispatcherHelper)

Without Initializing the DispatcherHelper, when it gets to the delegate call it throws a null exception, as expected, so I need the initialization.  Is there a problem with initializing it within the UnitTest? I just can't imagine why it would work in the context of a single unit test, but not any more than that.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds awful.  You could abstract it out and wrap the calls in a mockable object so you can intercept these types of calls in unit tests...

Comment: Hmmm... That is a possibility that I did not think of.  So you have no idea why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: Sorry, haven't ever used MVVM Light.  Isn't that open source?  Might be worth fixing the issue for your own use and submitting the result as a patch.

Comment: @Will: I would post that suggestion as an answer, as that in my opinion is exactly how to deal with situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The real problem seems to be that MsTest throws the UnitTests off into different threads at the same time just to get them all done quickly, and the "initialize" for the dispatcher has the following code:

```
Initialize()
{
    if (UIDispatcher != null)
    { return null }
    else // initialize
}
```

That means you can only initialize it once without clearing it, and it ends up initialized only for that thread.  Yet since the unit tests are all on different threads, you end up with issues where it will pass over any calls to the Dispatcher.  I'm trying to find a built-in way to "de-initialize" it (thus setting UIDispatcher back to null), but as Will suggested simply editing the code might be best.